# IPC shared memory std::vector in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, stdvector

I have two win32 programs, and they communicate with one DLL via IPC. I use MSVC ++ so it makes sense that I use CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile. I already have some codes done, the problem is that when my second program starts and loads a DLL and starts to work with DLLs, everything is fine and IPC communication is going well. When the first program starts and loads a DLL and starts to work with DLLs and the second program starts and loads a DLL and starts to work with DLLs, second program stops communicating with DLL via IPC. The IPC communication is probably running but probably in wrong way. It obtains the size and capacity, but the content is junk. The content of the shared memory is vector of pointers! What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I need to know to get those work fine?

```
//The sender writer
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
}

void MainWindow::SetData(vector <SubWindow*> &iMainWin)
{
    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(vector <SubWindow*>), TEXT("MyMappedMem"));

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
        return;

    vector <SubWindow*> *pBuf = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<SubWindow*>*> (MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(vector <SubWindow*>)));

    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return;
    }

    memcpy(pBuf, &iMainWin, sizeof(iMainWin));
    return;
}

//The reciever reader 
void DataWork()
{
    do{
       if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, "Win32Project.exe") == 0)
       {
           bProcessFound = true;
           break;
       }
     } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

     if (!bProcessFound)
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("ERROR Process32Next Openning DLL"), TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);
         return;
     }
     else
     {
        HANDLE hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, TEXT("MyMappedMem"));

        if (hMapFile == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("ERROR OpenFileMapping DLL"), TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);
            return;
        }

        vector<SubWindow*> *pBuf = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<SubWindow*>*> (MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(vector <SubWindow*>)));

        if (pBuf == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("ERROR MapViewOfFile DLL"), TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);
            CloseHandle(hMapFile);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < buf->size(); i++)
            (*buf)[i]->value_access;

        UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
     }
}
```

Comment: That's complitelly wrong. sizeof of your vector is not the same as the size of the data that is inside that vector. Try to output the sizeof of vector of 100 ints. It will be something like 20 bytes, see? You need to change the way you save the data in the memory

Comment: File mapping is likely the wrong solution. Why did you settle on that?

Answer (score 2):

Pointers in the first program are useless in the second program, and vice versa. You cannot use a pointer from program A in program B because they have different virtual memory spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to share a `std::vector` using shared memory is almost certainly wrong.  The `std::vector` will allocate memory from the calling process, which will not be accessible via any other process.  Furthermore, pointers pointing to local addresses will not be accessible any other process.

Additionally, you would need to coordinate access to the `std::vector` using a mutex, which you aren't doing.

In this situation, I can't see any reason why using a text file wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: A text file is probably the worst idea, when you want to implement IPC. Who is going to clean up the garbage you threw on the sidewalk, for example? What coherence guarantees are in place? How do you signal modifications? How do you signal, when it's safe to consume the data? Way easier and way more appropriate: Serialize the data and transmit it over a (named) pipe.

Comment: The example doesn't use any actual IPC.  Shared memory, and IPC in general, should be avoided unless it's absolutely necessary.  However, yes there are other mechanisms that avoid the complexity of synchronizing access, and give better semantics.

Comment: The example **does** use IPC. It starts with `CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(vector <SubWindow*>), TEXT("MyMappedMem"))`, and gets remapped into another instance of the same module (in another process).

Comment: No, it doesn't.  The example establishes shared memory, but it doesn't use it for IPC.  No processes are communicating.  What the incorrect example does is attempt to share a `std::vector` instantiated in the first process, in which case a simple text format would suffice.  If you think I'm wrong, write an answer describing how you would re-write the example using a socket or a named pipe.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the example. The code is compiled into a DLL. This DLL is linked into two separate processes. One of them calls `SetData`, the other process calls `DataWork`. The same filemapping object is accessed from both processes. This is called IPC. The way it is implemented doesn't work as expected. Nonetheless, IPC is the documented intent.

Comment: The data is entirely static in the example.  If that wasn't the intent, it's up to the O.P. to clarify.  You're welcome to add your own answer, but I'm not going to recommend using IPC when it isn't necessary.

Comment: The call to `memcpy` copies the data into the filemapping object in one process, and the `reinterpret_cast` and indexing operator read the data in another process. Since `iMainWin` is an input to `SetData`, I don't see, how you conclude that it were static. The intent is to have process B access dynamic data provided by process A. The implementation uses IPC, and the question **clearly** details this.

Comment: Add another answer.  There are a lot of issues with the example, and my personal opinion is that IPC shouldn't be encouraged unless there's a valid justification.